# Throw exception if page is 404

Tags: java, selenium, exception

I am accessing thousands of URLs via Java Selenium. I think some of these are 404s or 500. I want to if the response is other than 200 than throw an exception.

I know Jmeter can do it, I also know it's a bad practice to throw exceptions like this, but due to some limitations in the framework, it can only report exception in final reports. We are capturing exception in JUnit's `@After` block

What I tried is this, but it doesn't throw an exception. What am I missing in this code?

```
    if (getDriver().getTitle().contains("404")) {
        syso("throw exception, page is 404");
        try {
            throw new MalformedURLException("page not found");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        consoleLogs("Page found ...");
    }
```

I think it is not throwing exception because I have handled it. But if I don't handle it gives compilation error.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: The compilation error probably says the exception must be caught or **declared to be thrown**. So you want to declare it thrown, not to catch it.

Comment: You will need to add something like method()  throws Exception{} https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424284/unreported-exception-java-lang-exception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-throw/37424329

Comment: Selenium might not be the tool you want to use for this job. However you could use browsermob proxy to more easily capture the request data (including response)

Comment: malformed url's are not 404's

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being thrown but your code catches it right after.

Remove the try/catch block and change your method's signature like this:

```
public void methodName() throws MalformedURLException {}
```